# How to access pdf file outside of public_html in joomla site?

Tags: pdf, server, directory, joomla, cpanel

Actually i want to edit a module to fetch PDF file outside from public_html.

I already tried to change permission of that file from which i want to fetch PDF to 777.

### I am trying to fetch PDF by following codes

```
$baseurl = JURI::base();
$outside_baseurl = $baseurl.'../pdf/name.pdf';
```

### Shows this error

```
Cannot access file!
https://mysitedomain.com/../pdf/name.pdf
```

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, you might like to join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not safe to access a file outside the scope of your public folder in the open like that. It has the potential to open serious security holes. If you are trying to do this to modify or use the PDF file for something inside PHP, you should be able to. If you are trying to send it to a user for download or preview, you might wanna try   [`fpassthru()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php). Something like the example below.

```
<?php

$path = 'path/to/file.pdf';

$public_name = basename($path);

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $path);

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$public_name;");
header("Content-Type: $mime_type");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));

$fop = fopen($path, 'rb');
fpassthru($fop);
exit;
```

This should serve your purpose.